# Dutch National Flag Problem in EPI in Python book questions

Tags: python, algorithm, quicksort, partitioning

I am reading the book [Elements of Programming Interviews in Python](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1537713949). On page 40, I struggle to make sense of the following:

> "Generalizing, suppose A = (0, 1, 2, 0, 2, 1, 1), and the pivot index
> is 3. Then A[3] = 0, so i) (0, 0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 1) is a valid
> partitioning. For the same array, if the pivot index is 2, then A[2] =
> 2, so the arrays ii) (0,1,0,1,1,2,2) as well as iii) (0,0,1,1,1,2,2)
> are valid partitionings."

The requirement is to take an array A and an index i into A, and rearranges the elements such that all elements less than A[i] (the "pivot") appear first, followed by elements equal to the pivot, followed by elements greater than the pivot.

My questions for the quoted:

1. Why is i) (0,0,1,2,2,1,1) a valid partitioning? I can't understand why it is acceptable that there are A[4] and A[5] which are both 1 and less than the new A[3], i.e. 2. Isn't the definition "less than, on its left; equal followed by greater than"?
2. For ii) (0,1,0,1,1,2,2), why is A[2] changed from 2 to 0? Isn't A[2] in the original A, has its left elements less than it already?

Thanks.

Comment: The definition of partition has absolutely nothing to do with what's going to be the new element at the specified index.  I pick an index, and I look at the element at that index.  Everything less than that value gets entered, then my item, then items equal to the pivot, then items bigger than the pivot.

Comment: In the first example, the pivot is 0.  So everything less than 0 (nothing) then all the 0s, then everything bigger.  In the second example, everything less than 2, then all the twos, then everything bigger than 2 (nothing).  The element that ends up in the pivot slot afterwards is irrelevant.

Comment: Your explanation helps a lot,, @frank-yellin. Is it correct that the pivot is a value to be referred to for entering the value ( including the pivot value itself) in the order of "less than, equal and greater than"? Thanks.

Comment: Correct.  The pivot is just a value to compare everything else against.  I assume you're looking at QuickSort.  QS words by picking a pivot, putting everything smaller than the pivot on the left and everything bigger than the pivot on the right.  You now have sort the two sides independently of each other, and the result will be a sorted list.